# What is __meteor_bootstrap__?

Tags: meteor

I am just starting with Meteor and working on an existing project.  I am running into an issue with one of the packages(observatory-apollo) that's has the following line:

```
      __meteor_bootstrap__.app.use Observatory.logger #TLog.useragent
```

It is complaining that `__meteor_bootstrap__.app` is undefined.

What is `__meteor_boostrap__` exactly? I can't seem to find a description of what it is but from threads, people seem to know how to use it.  I can only see it defined in boot.js, but it doesn't really tell me much...

Comment: probably a reference to twitter bootstrap?  have you installed the bootstrap package?

Comment: Tried that, but doesn't seem to help.  Looks like it's something different.  Kinda odd...

Comment: Appears to be an environmental variable: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/d477c8d03bb078f7e8e85dbe4b51db7ae5689573/tools/unipackage.js

Comment: Well, the way it is used looks like Express way of adding middleware, except that I can't seem to find the code that adds middleware.  So this is probably something that's been deprecated, but I am just guessing...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meteor uses `connect` npm module under the hood for various reasons, to serve static files, for example. `__meteor_bootstrap__.app` was the reference to `connect` app instance.

Before it was `__meteor_bootstrap__.app` but it changed couple of releases ago and became `WebApp.connectHandlers` object and is part of `WebApp` package.

`WebApp` is a standard package of Meteor, core package for building webapps. You don't usually need to add explicitly as it is a dependency of `standard-app-packages`.

Example of usage the `connectHandlers` is to inject connect middlewares in the same way as you would use any `connect` middleware (or some `express` middlewares, express is built on top of `connect`):

```
WebApp.connectHandlers
    .use(connect.query())
    .use(this._config.requestParser(bodyParser))
```

You can look at `meteor-router` Atmosphere package and take it as an example: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router/blob/master/lib/router_server.js

More about `connect`: https://npmjs.org/package/connect

Comment: Yep, `__meteor_bootstrap__.app` is equivalent to `Webapp.connectHandlers`. Just make sure you `app.use('webapp', 'server');` in order to get it.

Comment: @AndrewMao Thanks for additions, I will revise my answer