# Spawning child tcp server in meteor

Tags: sockets, tcp, meteor

I want to create a Meteor application that interacts with the user and at the same time receives market data from multiple TCP sockets. I intend to channel the market data (from various TCP sockets) into one collection.

I had been looking around but i do not see a net.createServer method for Meteor. Can anyone give any pointers for me to start?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor has a packaging system that allows you to use node modules.  So I would look at node modules to find the server functionality you want to add. The [node core module](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_http) `http` might be a good start.

You can also just search the [NPM registry](https://npmjs.org/) for a module with functionality that fits your needs better.  Then just include it in you Meteor app through the [packaging system](http://docs.meteor.com/#writingpackages).  I have included the NPM [pubsubhubbub](https://npmjs.org/package/pubsubhubbub) in an rss aggregator that listens for pings and fills client collections so the [package I used](https://github.com/mikowals/simple_rss/tree/master/packages/pubsubhubbub) might be an example to follow.

Listening for data arriving on other ports or other domains will not work for a deployment on meteor.com so I think what you are describing will also require you to host the app.

Comment: Meteor version 0.6.5 also has WebApp which may be the easiest approach.  Discussions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499625/how-do-i-setup-an-api-to-access-my-meteor-collection/18505608#18505608), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283815/push-arbitrary-data-to-a-meteor-server/18283989#18283989), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265750/what-is-meteor-bootstrap/18278074#18278074).

Comment: Oh! I had not considered deployment issues on meteor.com. But you raised an important consideration. I will have to host the app then.

Comment: With WebApp you can avoid hosting yourself. I think WebApp is the more 'meteorish' way but the NPM in package route might be quicker if you can build on something that already exists.

Comment: `WebApp` is just a Meteor variable for the [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) server framework for Node to which you can add middleware. Anything you can attach to connect, you can attach to Meteor as well.